# Changing the color of a row on click

Tags: javascript

Using pure javascript only:

How can I click on a specified table row, and change the background color of the selected row (for this example, lets use the color red).

Then, if the same row that was previously selected is clicked on again, change its background color back to default (white).

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-ca">

</head>

<body>

<table border="1" cellspacing="1" width="100%" id="table1">
    <tr>
        <th>Column1</th>
        <th>Column2</th>
        <th>Column3</th>
        <th>Column4</th>
        <th>Column5</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
    </tr>
</table>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: With "pure JavaScript" do you mean that you cannot use additional libraries like jQuery? If so then why?

Comment: Please add the JavaScript part you're working on too, so that someone can help to improve it.

Comment: A simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/5YYsL/

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063935/javascript-table-select

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('tr').click(function () {
        //Check to see if background color is set or if it's set to white.
        if(this.style.background == "" || this.style.background =="white") {
            $(this).css('background', 'red');
        }
        else {
            $(this).css('background', 'white');
        }
    });
});
```

[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/QyZNQ/)

Answer (score 6):

something like this on your tr's would work ..

```
<tr onclick="this.style.backgroundColor='red'">
```

EDIT:  didn't read your question properly ..

this would work:

```
<script>
    function changeColor(o){
        o.style.backgroundColor=(o.style.backgroundColor=='red')?('transparent'):('red');
    }
</script>
```

and on your tr:

```
<tr onclick="changeColor(this)">
```

Answer (score 3):

use jQuery and see example on http://jsfiddle.net/X2pJN/

```
$('table tr').each(function(a,b){
    $(b).click(function(){
         $('table tr').css('background','#ffffff');
         $(this).css('background','#ff0000');   
    });
});
```

Comment: NP, but jQuery IS pure javascript.