# Highlight a selected Object with a background color in css

Tags: css, html-table, selecteditem

In a Table structure i have Selected a particular row that one row which i have selected should be highlighted with a backgorund color in css code

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Should the row change background colour when hovered? If so, then add `table tr:hover { background-color: red }` to the CSS file.

Comment: Add what you've come up with.

Comment: the row color should change which i click or select  that particular row. @DebsmitaPaul

Comment: You can check https://stackoverflow.com/q/17843478/12730938
and
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2064039/12730938